# Why can't I redefine the : operator in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, operator-overloading

I'm trying to reimplement some functionality of the list data type in Haskell for learning purposes. When I try to redefine `:` with this code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude #-}

data List a = Nil
            | Cons a (List a)

(:) :: a -> List a -> List a
(:) = Cons
```

I get the following error with `stack runghc`:

> Invalid type signature: (:) :: ...
>
> Should be of form <variable> :: <type>

Is it impossible to redefine `:`? Is that why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is impossible to redefine `:`, but that is not why you are getting that error. You are getting that error because `:` is considered "upper-case punctuation" -- that is, any name that starts with `:` must be an (infix) value constructor. Nevertheless, even with `NoImplicitPrelude` and `RebindableSyntax` turned on, you will find that, e.g.

```
data Foo = Foo : Foo
```

gives you an error, saying:

```
error: Illegal binding of built-in syntax: :
```

Presumably with some extra engineering effort, a future GHC could support redefining `:` with some suitable extensions turned on, but for now it's not possible.

Comment: Interesting! Is there any documentation for `:` being "upper-case punctuation"? I can't find any references to that term.

Comment: @DylanSp The [Haskell Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch2.html#x7-180002.4) is the canonical source. See especially the production rule for *consym*, though the whole linked section is pretty related. To help you read these rules, the subscript notation in production rules means "all of the things in the normal text, except none of the things in the subscripted text" (this is described earlier in the document).