# Haskell: What is the meaning of :.?

Tags: haskell, cons

A symbol combined (:.) of cons following by a dot.

Taken from here:

```
-- The custom list type
data List t =
  Nil
  | t :. List t
  deriving (Eq, Ord)

-- Right-associative
infixr 5 :.
```

Taken from here: https://github.com/tonymorris/fp-course

Comment: It is the same as `data List t = Nil | Cons t (List t)` but instead of `Cons` it uses an infix constructor `(:.)`. The FP course should this clear

Comment: To be clear, `:.` isn't a built-in operator, it's being defined in the code you've given.

Comment: `.` is to `:.` as `foo` is to `Foo`. Just as an initial capital letter distinguishes between a regular function and a data constructor, an initial colon distinguishes between an infix operator and an infix data constructor.

Comment: [See also](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48161715/791604) (possibly duplicate?).

Answer (score 6):

**In short**: the code constructs an alterative version of a list, and `(:.)` is one of the two *data constructors*.

Well it is a **data constructor** of the `List t` data type. For example the standard list `[a]` has two data constructors `[]` and `(:)`, here the code introduces a new data constructor `(:.)`, but it acts completely the same way as the "cons" of the standard list `(:)`.

So the code defines it as:

```
data List t = Nil | (:.) t (List t) deriving (Eq, Ord)
```

and like any data constructor, we can do pattern matching on it, construct new lists, etc.